# Windows XP port forwarding to VMware machines

Tags: windows-xp, vmware, port-forwarding

I have a Windows XP machine with two VMware machines running on it. The machines are running in network-bridged mode (but I can change them to NAT if needed). Windows XP machine has certain ports open from outside and I would like to forward them to VMware machines.

Is it possible with some XP built in mechanism? If not, what software would you recommend?

Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: If your virtual machines are really using bridged networking, then you shouldn't need to forward any ports from the host machine. Your virtual machines should have their own IP addresses and conceptually be on the same level as your Windows machine. If you are behind a router, forward ports from the router to the virtual machines.

Comment: Windows machine is behind a NAT and the router is configured to forward certain ports to Windows, now I need to dispatch them further on Windows machine. Also, I cannot change the configuration on router.